# Modifying keylayout file / using external keyboard input to mimic accelerometer

Tags: keyboard

We can modify/create a keylayout file for any input device in android from /System/USR/Keylayout/device_layout_file.kl (http://source.android.com/tech/input/key-layout-files.html)

Can we modify the keylayout file to take /mimic accelerometer input ?